# increasing sub array not strictly adjacent

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this problem. It is about an increasing sub array, I tried to implement such algorithm inspired by Kadane's algorithm. It seems not to pass my university's online judge. It fails test case 7. Can you help with it? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
//#include <climits>
#include <string>
#include<algorithm> 

using namespace std;

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    long long int n; cin >> n;
    long long int *a = new long long int[n];
    long long int *len = new long long int[n];
    for (long long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    for (long long int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        len[k] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[k]) {
                len[k] = max(len[k], len[i] + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    long long int res = len[n - 1];
    if (res == 1)
        res = -1;
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems not to pass my university's online judge. It fails test case 7. ==> What is case 7 about ? Please be more descriptive

Comment: @SabunkarTejasSahailesh It is not provided.

Comment: is this `len[i] + 1` correct or should be `len[i + 1]`?

Comment: Without knowing the unit test case which your code is breaking for, How can you expect any one to solve your problem ?

Comment: @SabunkarTejasSahailesh len[i]+1. Maybe by being more attentive.

Comment: I don't understand how are you expected to sort correctly when you actually add values that not necessarily exist in your input.txt by using this `len[k] = 1` and `len[i] + 1`

Comment: @Nap if your `input.txt` starts with a 0 value than you probably won't get the expected result. Perhaps changing to `len[k] = 0` may solve your problem

Comment: No, that won t change. It should be one.